# Button is not clickable in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a button on a website but it's not clicking even I tried find_element_by_xpath, id, class, and others.

this is what the element code of the button looks like

```
<button type="button" class="gpbutton" id="gtltranslate">Translate</button>
```

here is my code which opens a file and translates them into a nother file

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib as textmanager

PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
eng=[]

driver.get("https://www.webtran.eu/finnish_english_translator/")

input1= driver.find_element_by_id("gtlsource")
output1= driver.find_element_by_id("gtlresults_body")
btn= driver.find_element_by_class_name("gpbutton")

lines= []

with open("sanat.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #or some other preprocessing
        lines.append(line) #storing everything in memory!



k=0
while k != len(lines):
    input1.send_keys(lines[k])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    eng.append(output1)
    input1.clear()
    k=k+1
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is the error

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" class="gpbutton" id="gtltranslate">...</button> is not clickable at point (534, 490). Other element would receive the click: <span id="cookieconsent:desc" class="cc-message">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use WebDriverWait function to wait for the button to be loaded and clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to launch the browser in full screen mode  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

and then use the below css selector like this  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#gtltranslate"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**PS :** you can use screen maximize like this in your code :

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.webtran.eu/finnish_english_translator/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cc-compliance a"))).click()
```

Comment: hmm its not working i dont understand why

Comment: i think you need to click on cookies `Ok` button as well before interacting with any web element. can you try this `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cc-compliance a"))).click()`. Check the above updated code. I think you need to send something also to translate, right ?